# Using Oracle..Need to compare each row of column having 1 word content with rows of column having paragraphs as row values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column having n number of rows. Each row is having a single word as its value.
example "hello","there" etc
And i have another column having m number of rows.
Each row has a huge paragraph i need to compare each row of first column with every row in latter column.
Basically i need to find the particular words in the paragraphs , and identify the rows having even 1 word present in the row of first column.

Comment: It would help if you added sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to account for the word being at the beginning or end of a line and that the paragraphs will have normal punctuation characters at the of the line.

This should account for those cases.

```
select
word
,paragraph
from 
(select
'(\W|^)' || word || '(\W|$)' as regexp
,word
from t1
) t
join t2 on
 (regexp_instr(paragraph, t.regexp) > 0)
;
```

If you want case-insensitive searching then you can use this query

```
select
word
,paragraph
from 
(select
'(\W|^)' || word || '(\W|$)' as regexp
,word
from t1
) t
join t2 on 
    (regexp_instr(paragraph, regexp, 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0)
;
```

[Here is the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/097b2/4/0)

Comment: jwhite 9 Your ans was helpful as i can search words in the paragraphs perfectly.
But what i wanted was that if i find a row which has even 1 matched word. I should then and there stop my further iteration over that row and start comparing other rows.
As your solution will give me same row as many times as it matches no. of words in it with the word table

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner join and a like condition.

You may have a problem when one word is part of another word.  For instance, the word "the" is in "there", so a query on '%the%' will be true whenever the word "there" is in the paragraph, even if there is no occurrence of the word "the".  I'll use spaces before and after the word to prevent this, but that will miss words at the beginning and ending of the paragraph unless you (a) store a leading and trailing space in the paragraph table, or (b) use string concatenation in the query to do the same, which might (or might not) effect performance.

```
select *
from word_table
  inner join paragraph_table
     on ' ' || paragraph_table.paragraph || ' ' like '% ' || word_table.word || ' %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want... My example count occur. or word 'world' in the string. There two occur., so it it will return 2.

```
SELECT count(*) word_count  FROM
(
 SELECT Distinct(Instr('Hello world! So happy to meet you world!', 'world', LEVEL)) str_cnt
  FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL < length('Hello world! So happy to meet you world!') 
 ) 
WHERE str_cnt > 0
/
```

This will return 4:

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('Hello world world! So happy to meet you world world!', 'world') word_count
 FROM dual
/
```

If any of your rows have count of word more then 0-zero then you got a winner - you identified such row as you wrote in your description.